# Getting data from table after clicking Search Button

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing

I'm testing the Search function of my website by Selenium Webdriver. I'm trying to get the list of table after I've clicked Search button to compare with the input.

For example: There are 10 cars in the list and 2 cars named Tesla. If I give an input Tesla then click the Search button and the new list will only have 2 cars named Tesla. I need to get those 2 names to compare with the input but It seems my code is getting the list before I click the Search button.

Error: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected: <test update 2>. Actual: Exciter.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much

Here is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
        [DataRow("Exciter")]
        public void Search_XE_with_Name(String Name)
    {

        Login();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL + "/app/admin/xe-group11");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        Thread.Sleep(8000);
        //Act

        driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_NAME")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_NAME")).SendKeys(Name);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);

        IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/span[3]/button"));
        IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);


        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(3000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,ts);
        //IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/div[2]/div/p-table/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
        //IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        //List<String> Name1 = new List<String>();

        IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/p-table/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
        IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        //IList<IWebElement> rowtd;
        var listName = new List<string>();

        foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
        {
            var secondColumn = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[2];
            listName.Add(secondColumn.Text);
        }

        foreach (String names in listName)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(names, Name);
        }            

        driver.Close();
    }
```

[image: Before Search]
[image: After Search]

Comment: When the search is performed on page does it reloads the table with searched data or it hides the rows and displays only searched rows? You need to debug the test and check how many items you are getting in `rows` variable. Also you are passing parameters in wrong order to Assert.Equals method.

Comment: Thank you sir. It seems you're right. It hides the rows and displays only searched rows. How can I solve this or is there any other way to test the Search function? I can't find any approaches to test it and this is just my trial and error way

Comment: You need to select only `tr` which are not hidden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237927/how-to-obtain-only-visible-elements-inside-an-html-table-using-jquery